# how to get value by data id in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider I have user `data-rowid="123"` and its value is `data-loc="abc"`
I want to get data-loc value find by data-rowid
here is my original html

```
<input type="checkbox" data-rowid="{{ $customer->id }}" data-loc="{{ $customer->location_url }}"/>
```

i have button when user click on it then it call that finction `.map-checked-box`

javascript which i tried

```
$("body").delegate('.map-checked-box', 'click', function(){
      var a = $(this).data('id');
      var b = $(this).find.('a').data("loc");
      console.log(b);
     });
```

****but this code only get data-rowid in (a) but doesnot find loc value**

**any help will be thankfull****

Comment: Sidenote: `As of jQuery 3.0, .delegate() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method since jQuery 1.7` - docs: https://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: In your example the `data-loc` attribute is on an `input` element, not on an `a` element. Therefore `$(this).find('a').data("loc");` won't work. Maybe you want `$(this).data("loc");` or `$(this).find('input').data("loc");` but it's not clear since your example is not consistent.

Comment: @FelixKling I think they're trying the `a` variable not `a` as in a hyperlink!

Comment: Given that you have `data-rowid=` you should use `.data('rowid')` instead of `.data('id')`

Comment: @Jamiec: Ah, I guess that could be true. But then what is the value of `a` supposed to be? Certainly not clear how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @FelixKling Reading the id into `a` and then trying to look up by that id to get loc - at least thats how I read/answered it. I could be wrong. Probably shouldnt have answered until that was clear.

Comment: Are you trying to get the `loc` of the _clicked checkbox_ by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][data-rowid='"+ yourRowId +"']").attr("data-loc")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of inconsistencies in your code, along with a long-ago deprecated call to `delegate` - but the below should hopefully demonstrate how you can use `filter` to find an element by `data-rowid` and then read `data-loc`:

```js
$("body").on('click', '.map-checked-box', function(){
  var result = $('input').filter( (i,e) => $(e).data("rowid") == 123).data("loc");
  console.log(result);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-rowid="123" data-loc="abc"/>

<button class="map-checked-box">click me</button>
```

Comment: thanx for your help but there is one thing u are fixing data("rowid") == 123 rowid can be different so i donot want to fix it as 123

Comment: @HamzaQureshi that can be a variable, It was just to demonstrate how you find this. If thats not what you're asking you need to clarify _in the question_